# Java: .Class searcher

Tags: java, class, search

What i need is a little application which allows me to search multiple .class files for a word. Can that be done with which application?

Comment: It sort of depends if your word is compiled away or not. But, `javap` might help.

Comment: You do realize that .class files are binary (compiled), right? I think you mean .java files.

Comment: @Christian String literals will still be in the .class file, but you're probably right about really wanting to search .java files.

Comment: Very exotic need )) Consider decompiling `*.class` files instead using some tool like JAD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep. Grep solves all.

E.g: `grep word *.class`

Comment: Now, the output may be particularly ugly.  But you can set options so it'll just tell you what files match, without showing you the matches.

Comment: I'd suggest "grep -iR word *.class". Used from the root directory for class files. Searches recursively and case independently

Comment: Then you can use JD-GUI to decompile the class file and get good output. http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui